# Django no module named "compressor"

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2015, django-compressor

I'm trying to create a super user using cmd but every time I run the command I get:

```
C:\Users\PCDOM\Desktop\Power\pm_app>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in popu
late
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 86, in create

    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named compressor
```

Even though I have it installed in my virtual environment and in my settings.py:

[image]

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'bootstrap3',
    'promo',
    'ums',
    'compressor',
    #'sqlserver_ado',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Any reason django is spasing out on me?

Comment: have to tried this one http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/

Comment: I just deleted django-compressor and tried to use that link since that;'s what I was looking at earlier but now it's giving me installation problems

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So pretty much I had to install django-compressor using my local pip, so for some reason it's not utilizing my virtual environments compressor

Comment: The missing package is `django-compressor` **NOT** `django_compressor`

Answer (score 5):

You need to reinstall django_compressor in your Venv

```
 pip install django_compressor
```